# Irreducible subspace of $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X:=V(x^m-y^n)$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{A}^2$. How can I prove that if $(n,m)=1$ then $X$ is irreducible?

I think that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$ but I can't prove that.

Comment: It's not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$; if $m, n \ge 2$ it has a singularity at the origin.

Comment: It cannot be isomorphic to $P^1$, because there are non-constant regular functions on it (for example, the restrictions to it of the coordinate functions) (More generally, no algebraic subset of an affine space is projective)

Comment: Ha. I meant it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, which I assume is what Jacob meant.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yup, that's a more likely conjecture. A simple way to see it is not an $A^1$, avoiding determining singularities, is to see that the coordinate ring of $X$ is not integrally closed (this is almost the same thing, really, but proving so requires a bit of work)

Comment: @Mariano: I think you meant to say "no non-finite subset of affine space is projectve" (as a special case of the general fact that finite = projective (or even proper) + affine).

Comment: Yeah, that :) ${}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove that it is irreducible, show that it is the image of an irreducible space under a continuous map.

For example, you should have no trouble finding a map $\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb A^2$ whose image is your $X$.

Comment: @Jacob Fox: Dear Jacob, If you complete Mariano's exercise, you will also see that it is *birational* to $\mathbb P^1$, although is is not actually isomorphic to (any open subset of) $\mathbb P^1$, as noted in the comments to the question.  Regards,